# In InDesign, is it possible to auto generate a third curve which averages two others?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have two curves, both were drawn with the pen tool and have the same number of anchor points. The first curve is relatively smooth and the second very angular.

Is it possible to create a third curve which is the average of the two, ideally taking account of X and Y coordinates as well as curve radius. Then can the align tool be used to evenly distribute the three objects?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead simple in Illustrator -- Don't think it's possible in InDesign.

Possible workaround...

In **Illustrator**....

- Draw left and right curves (Or copy them from INDD and paste them into a new Illustrator document - you may need to `Object > Ungroup` in Illustrator after pasting.)
- Choose `Object > Blend > Make`
- Choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options`
- Set the options to `Specified Steps` and enter `1` in the field. The "middle" path will be auto-generated as an average between the two existing paths and be centered between them.
- Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` to "bake in" the blend, resulting in 3 simple, standard, paths.
- Copy.. paste back into InDesign

Paths from Illustrator should paste as (grouped) paths back into InDesign. Merely ungroup in InDesign to gain access to each separate path if necessary.